# How many positive 5-digit integers whose digits are from A (digits can be repeated) which are strictly greater than 46000 are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

So my analysis of this question uses the _ _ _ _ _ method.

Since the first number is restricted to 3 numbers (4,5,6), it's "3".

The second number is what I am having trouble on, if the first number is a 4 then the second number can be a 6 in 46000. But if the first number is a 5, then the second number can be any from "A".

The other lines are 6, 6, 6. So what I have is 3 _ 6 6 6.

Comment: Can digits be repeated?  If so, break into cases.  Case 1: The first digit is a four.  Case 2: The first digit is larger than a 4.  Apply the addition principle and multiplication principle.

Comment: break into cases: numbers starting with 4 + numbers starting with 5 or 6.

Comment: Yes numbers can be repeated. So my answer now is (2*6*6*6*6)+(1*1*6*6*6) with first case being with numbers greater than 4 and second case being first number is a 4.

Comment: Make sure to subtract "1" because your second case also includes the number "46000", which is not strictly greater than 46000.

Comment: @mathguy No the second case doesn't because since the set A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}, there is no 0 number (:

Answer (score 4):

If the first digit is $5$ or $6$, then anything following these values is valid. Thus, we have $2\times 6\times 6\times 6\times 6$ of such numbers.

If the first digit is $4$, then the second digit must be $6$, and the rest of the digits can be any of the other digits, i.e. we have $1\times 1\times 6\times 6\times 6$ of such numbers.

Hence, you would have the sum of the above two cases.

Answer (score 1):

"*Addition principle*":

> If $E\cap F=\emptyset$ (*i.e. are disjoint sets*) then $|E\cup F|=|E|+|F|$.
>
> In other words, if we can *partition* a set into disjoint subsets, then the total number of elements in the set is the sum of the total number of elements in each part.

Here, we take the set "All valid numbers" and break it into the two sets "All valid numbers whose first digit is a four" and "All valid numbers whose first digit is not a four."

Such a process is often also called "breaking into cases."

Under the assumption that the question intends "greater than or equal to $46000$"

- Case 1: First digit is a four.  How many valid numbers exist in this case?

  - Pick the first digit (It must be a four)
  - Pick the second digit (It must be a six)
  - Pick the third digit (It can be anything from $A$)
  - $\vdots$
- Case 2: First digit is not a four.  How many valid numbers exist in this case?

  - Pick the first digit (It can only be a $5$ or $6$)
  - Pick the second digit (It can be anything from $A$)
  - Pick the third digit (It can be anything from $A$)
  - $\vdots$

In each case, apply multiplication principle for the subtotal, and then get the final total by adding the results.

> $1\cdot 1\cdot 6^3 + 2\cdot 6^4$

In the case that the question intends "is strictly greater than $46000$" then we counted one too many when we included it as a possibility in the first case, so by subtracting one we correct the count.

---

*Note:* The above "addition principle" is a special case of a more general result called **Inclusion-Exclusion** which says that for any two sets, $E$ and $F$, one has

$$|E\cup F|=|E|+|F|-|E\cap F|$$

noting that if $E\cap F=\emptyset$ the final term in the above equates to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Add up the following:

- There are $6^{5-2}=216$ numbers which start with $46$
- There are $6^{5-1}=1296$ numbers which start with $5$
- There are $6^{5-1}=1296$ numbers which start with $6$